# If a sequence of rational numbers converges to irrational number do the numerator and denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, irrational-numbers

I’m attempting to solve the following question:
$a_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers, for better understanding let’s write it as: $p_n/q_n$ (where $p<n$ and $q_n$ are sequences over the naturals $\Bbb N$).
If the limit of an (when $n$ diverges (to infinity)) is $r$ which is an irrational number :
$$\lim a_n = r| r\in \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$$
Does that mean that $p_n$ and $q_n$ both diverge (to infinity)?

I’ve found many examples that support this theorem but examples aren’t proof so I’m not sure if it’s actually true and why? Is there a way to prove it or is it just a known fact?

Comment: Could you please use Mathjax to format your Question and describe a few of the examples you found? I believe your question doesn't meet community guidelines and may attract close votes or downvotes.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. As to your question: if a sequence of integers like $p_n$  converges, then $p_n$ is eventually constant: for some $N$, $p_n = p_N$ for all $n \ge N$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yessss..... It's a weird question but for the rational numbers to converge to finite but irrational value the rational numbers themselves must become more and more "precise".  For tighter rational precision You do need a larger denominator (which can be thought of as "resolution" or "gradation")  And if the denominator is large and the ratio of the numerator to the denominator is more or less a specific value, then the numerator must be (near) proportionally as large.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Hint: If $p_n, q_n \in \Bbb{N}$ and say $q_n \neq 0$ (depends on how one defines $\Bbb{N}$) and say $p_n \rightarrow p$, then $p \in \Bbb{N}$, same for $q_n$ so...

Comment: @AnuragA  No need for $p_n\in \mathbb N$ if $\frac {p_n}{q_n}$ converge to a negative irrational number.

Comment: @fleablood I garee with you but I read OP's question as $p_n$ being a sequence over ''natural'' numbers.

Answer (score 6):

If both $p_n$ and $q_n$ are bounded, then, by virtue of them being integers, there are only a finite number of values that $(p_n, q_n)$ can assume. So $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ can only assume a finite number of values (all rational numbers), which means that the limit $r$ has to be rational (and in fact, the sequence is constant and equal to $r$ for large values of $n$).

If exactly one of $p_n$ or $q_n$ is bounded, then $r$ is either $0$ or $+\infty$, neither of which is an irrational.

Conclusion: Both have to be unbounded.

As @orangeskid said, since every subsequence is unbounded, the sequences tend to infinity.

Comment: Since every subsequence of $p_n$ is unbounded, we conclude $p_n\to \infty$ ( assume all positive).

Answer (score 2):

Both $\ P=\{p_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\ $ and $\ Q=\{q_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\ $ are bounded below by $\ 1.$

If $\ P\ $ is bounded above and $\ Q\ $ is not bounded above, then $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{q_n}=0,\ $ which is not irrational.

If $\ P\ $ is bounded above and $\ Q\ $ is bounded above, then the number of different fractions that $\ \frac{p_n}{q_n}\ $ can be is $\ \leq\ \max(P) \max(Q),\ $ which is finite (under the assumption that $\ P\ $ and $\ Q\ $ are both bounded above). The limit of a sequence of a finite amount of different rational numbers cannot be irrational.

If $\ P\ $ is not bounded above and $\ Q\ $ is bounded above then $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{q_n}\ $ is not a finite number and therefore cannot be irrational.

If $\ P\ $ is not bounded above and $\ Q\ $ is bounded above then it is possible for $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{q_n}\ $ to be irrational.